# Doctrine 2: How to remove the relation as well as the entity in a many-to-many association

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm

I have two entities `Category` and `Image`, a category can have many images, so it is basically one-to-many relation, but `Image` can also be referenced from other entities. That is why I am doing a many-to-many with a unique=true constraint through a mm table.

So my structure is something like this:

```
category
-- id

images
-- id

category_images
-- category_id
-- image_id
```

Now I simply want to delete images from a category by doing something like:

```
$category->images = new ArrayCollection();
```

or

```
unset($category->images);
```

The problem here is this only removes the connections, e.g. the records in the mm table (`category_images`), which is correct, but I need maybe an annotation that would, upon deletion of the mm records, also delete the related records in the `images` table?

I know this is a bit off the idea of mm, but I have no case in which a single image is referenced by two entities, so it should work for me.

Final idea is to have the ability to attach images to different entities, and provide an easy "automatic" way of deleting them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can set your tables to use Engine=InnoDB, you can use foreign key constraints to automatically delete the row in the child table or tables when the row in the parent table is deleted. See the details on

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html.